# Scrolling Tabhost at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I used the tabhost tutorial to get started with the Tabhost control.

After some play around I wanted to make the tabhost scrollable, which I figured out.

Now I want the tabhost at the bottom of the display which is just not working for me.

Switched to Relative Layout which was suggested here: [iPhone-like Tabbar](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android.html)

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:isScrollContainer="true">
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I need a hint why it's not working / how this would work. I tried with relative layout and `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` now it's there a few times (in the HorizontalScrollView and the TabWidget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Arve leading me to "custom controls" I found a promising project:

https://github.com/honcheng/ScrollableTabHost-for-Android

I hope some others looking for this kind of tabhost can use it :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible library to help you do this:
http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/

From their project description:

> Due to limitation of Android Tab component I created a custom TabWidget that I am using in couple different projects already. The widget allows us to add custom background and use custom icons, tabs can be Top/Bottom aligned.

EDIT: I have not tested this myself, but it looks promising.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this... was already thinking of a custom tabhost but I was hoping for an "easy" solution since I'm new to Android. I downloaded the sample but still have problems running it...

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get this running, after 20min of trying to find the errors (with the sample demo) I moved along...